# epsilon and varepsilon rendering in pslatex

Tags: pdftex, greek, ps

I have a very simple article, with one line:

```
$\epsilon \gtrsim \varepsilon$
```

If I use `pdflatex` to compile, `\epsilon` and `\varepsilon` are rendered in a different way, which is the correct behaviour.

However, I have to use `pslatex`, which renders both `\epsilon` and `\varepsilon` in the same way.

Why is this so? Can you reproduce this behaviour, or perhaps I am missing a package?

Edit. My working example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

  $\varepsilon \gtrsim \epsilon$

\end{document}
```

Also, to clarify: I do not need both renderings in my document. I need only `\epsilon`. However `\epsilon` is rendered as `\varepsilon` by `pslatex`

Comment: Perhaps it depends on which command do you use? I too get two different symbols with `pdflatex example.tex`, but not with `pslatex example.tex`

Comment: Perhaps, I am not sure. Part of the question was why `pdflatex` can compile correctly while `pslatex` cannot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two forms `\epsilon` and `\varepsilon` are just graphical variants of the same letter and using both unnecessarily confuses readers.

The `pslatex` package is obsolete and deprecated. You should have

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

instead. Which doesn't solve your problem, anyway, because the Symbol font used for Greek letters doesn't have different glyphs for the two forms of epsilon (this agains shows one shouldn't rely on them being available).

You're luckier if you use NewTX, that sports different glyphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$\epsilon=\varepsilon$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you ***really*** want different glyphs using `mathptmx` (not `pslatex`, please, it is obsolete and shouldn't be used), then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\DeclareSymbolFont{epsilon}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathord}{epsilon}{"0F}

\begin{document}
$\epsilon=\varepsilon$
\end{document}
```

will do. But it's a hack and relies on having available the NewTX fonts. An even worse hack is to use Computer Modern Math Italic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\DeclareSymbolFont{epsilon}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathord}{epsilon}{"0F}

\begin{document}
$\epsilon=\varepsilon$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What should I use rather than pslatex then? Moreover, the packages that you have suggested do not improve the situation (when still using pslatex). In fact both commands get rendered as \varepsilon when all I need is a vanilla \epsilon. Thanks

Comment: @astabada As I said, you should not load `pslatex`. But, as I said, the “good” package to be used instead, that is, `mathptmx`, *doesn't have* different glyphs. Which is what I wrote. If you really need them use the code in the example document; the text font will be Times.

Comment: See my update of the question for a working example. I understand that I should not use `pslatex` to compile. But what other command line command - other than `pdflatex` - is to be used to create the document? `pdflatex` is not an option because it gives errors when compiling the full document, which includes `*eps` files.

Comment: @astabada You *can't* have two different glyphs with `pslatex` or `mathptmx`, because the font used hasn't the different forms. With `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` you *do* get different forms.

Comment: Should I ask another question on how to get `\epsilon` rendered properly with pslatex? At the moment `\epsilon` is rendered as `\varepsilon`. Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` does not solve the problem as both symbols are renedered as `\varepsilon`.

Comment: @astabada You probably were still loading `pslatex`. Don't, ever. I added a couple of hacks, pick the one that works for you. But, please, don't use the two forms with different meanings.

Comment: Solved. I think the command `pslatex` automatically loads the package with the same name. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @astabada I agree with egreg (for once), you really shouldn't be using pslatex this century (I wrote it last century, when things were different).

Comment: Would LuaTeX/XeTeX with `unicode-math` and the right fonts (like `lmodern`) help?

Answer (score 0):

As a researcher in the field of mechanics (dynamics, vibrations, stress and strain, etc.) I find the availability of both \epsilon (lunate) and `\varepsilon` very useful.  In mechanics, we often use `\varepsilon` to denote strain and \epsilon to denote a small quantity.  For example, I use `\epsilon` in delta-epsilon proofs, and also as the independent variable which is the coefficient of a variation in the calculus of variations.

Comment: I think this is not an answer to the question. By the way, here I've seen `\epsilon` used in Levi-Civita tensor, and `\varepsilon` for everything else.